# Ejb3 stateless bean with CMT

Tags: java, transactions, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Is it possible to have something like this? **Client code** in a thread with pseudo code :

```
transaction.begin();
ejb.method();
transaction.commit();
```

The `method()` belongs to an EJB3 stateless session bean, annotated with `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`.
The `method()` could set `setRollbackOnly()`.

If the ejb method sets the setRollbackOnly(), should there be some checks before trying to commit the transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could also set the transaction attribute on the called bean (method) to `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` to force a new transaction on your method.

BTW: make sure to call **proxied** methods if you specify a transaction attribute on a **method**.
I.e., calling a method of an ejb which has a specific transaction attribute set from within the **same** ejb  will not work as you expect...

Comment: Though you can use SessionContext.getEJB/LocalContext or getBusinessObject to reacquire the proxy if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

the default setting of SLSB is the Tx semantics you describe.

Manual rollback is possible by specifying EjbContext.setRollbackOnly() - this tells the Contaner (the 'C' in CMT) that it should not commit but toll back the Transaction.

If you want to completely set up the the transaction on your own, you can still mark the calling SLSB method as NotSupported and then inside manually open a Tx that you can forward to other SLSB calls.

Comment: May be it is my mistake, I did not explain the problem fully. The question was more: is it possible CMT to exists within application managed tx, as it is my case

Comment: So, if I understood. The Tx of the ejb, merged with the client application managed tx, is still managed by the container and is not correct to be manually committed nor roll-backed?

Comment: Thing is: if your bean is CMT, then the *C*ontainer manages. You are not supposed to do Tx stuff internally. You can mark for rollback though by a) using setRollbackOnly() or b) throwing an Exception that triggers the rollback (see also @ApplicationException). Now that you are talking of a client. The client Tx can be probagated to this EJB and is used there. Or if the client supplies no Tx, a new one is started (and ended on exit of the SLSB method).

Comment: Yes, the client Tx, which is application managed, is supplied to to ejb and becomes CMT. But what happens after the ejb.method() returns? The next line is transaction.commit() - one can get can not commit already roll-backed tx, right?

Comment: Yes, the commit will throw TransactionRolledbackException.  The EJB spec requires EJBContext.setRollbackOnly to have this behavior.  Typically, the container will do the equivalent of calling UserTransaction.setRollbackOnly.